# nova-api service shuts down automatically

Tags: 14.04, openstack, nova

I was trying to configure Nutron on my Network node, and I observed that nova-api service on my controller is stopped. I restarted the service, but for some odd reason it keeps failing.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.02 Server on a Virtual Box.

Please help ...

## nova-api SERVICE ON THE CONTROLLER NODE STOPS AUTOMATICALLY

```
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api stop/waiting
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api start
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api start/running, process 9070
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api stop/waiting
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# service nova-api status
nova-api stop/waiting
```

## NOVA SERVICES

```
root@controller:/home/XXXXXXX# ps -ef | grep nova
nova       911     1  0 12:48 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-cert --config-file=/etc/nova/nova.conf
nova       922     1  0 12:48 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-consoleauth --config-file=/etc/nova/nova.conf
nova       923     1  1 12:48 ?        00:00:48 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-conductor --config-file=/etc/nova/nova.conf
nova       925     1  0 12:48 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-scheduler --config-file=/etc/nova/nova.conf
nova       926     1  0 12:48 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-novncproxy --config-file=/etc/nova/nova.conf
nova      1930   923  0 12:48 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-conductor --config-file=/etc/nova/nova.conf
root      9284  3115  0 13:46 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nova
```

[LOGS](http://pastebin.com/sfkzezJ5)

[DEBUG](http://pastebin.com/pMwFsEXB)

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to answer but posting as it might help others. 
I had the same problem and I found out while installing nova-network and nova-api-metadata , nova-api package is getting uninstalled which was strange. 
After reinstalling nova-api package problem solved.

( Ubuntu 14.04 , openstack kilo version )